# How does session_regenerate_id works?

Tags: php, session, session-fixation

I've read about securing sessions awhile ago but I don't know if I am using it right. All I know is that it replaces the current ID with a new one.

So for example:

```
    $user = 'popo';

$_SESSION['user']= $user ;
    session_regenerate_id(true);
```

is that the right way of using session_regenerate_id?

Comment: possible duplicate of [when and why I should use session_regenerate_id()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965067/when-and-why-i-should-use-session-regenerate-id)

Comment: While it does appear to be a duplicate of the question found above, the answers there are very poor quality.