# Issues with session_regenerate_id()

Tags: php, session-variables

I am using Facebook's PHP SDK for validating users to leave comments and it works quite well. Once, validated, I store the user information in a session variable, but first call `session_regenerate_id()` and then reload the page. When the page reloads, the old session data is still available, including the Facebook SDK state variable, however, the session variable I added is not available. The following is a snippet of the code:

```
session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION[...] = ...;

header('Location: ...');
die();
```

If I take out the `session_regenerate_id()` then everything works perfectly. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

If I log `session_id()` every page load, I see that `session_regenerate_id()` generates a new id and the session contains everything I expect. However, when the page reload occurs, the session id is the previous session id and not the new one, hence I cannot access the new session variables. Why would this happen?

Comment: `<?php
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
$new_sessionid = session_id();
echo "New Session: $new_sessionid<br />";

print_r($_SESSION);
?>`

Comment: Why are you doing the `session_regenerate_id();` if you have a session use it

Comment: @Anant I did that and everything looks good. However, while testing that again, I did notice that the session id reported after the `session_regenerate_id()` is not the same when I reload the page, which is still the old session. So, I guess the question becomes, why isn't the session id actually changing?

Comment: @RiggsFolly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965067/when-and-why-i-should-use-session-regenerate-id (When and why I should use session_regenerate_id()?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of logging and scanning the headers being sent and received, I determined that when the initial session was created, the domain used for the cookie was: `.domain.com` (without the www). However, `session_regenerate_id()` was setting the domain for the cookie to: `www.domain.com`. When the browser made a determination of which to send, it always sent the original one, so the session used was always the old one. Once I manually deleted that cookie, everything worked fine.

To ensure this sort of thing doesn't happen again, I added the following before starting my session:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], true, true);
```

What is odd, the .htaccess file enforces www.domain.com for consistency, so I am not sure why the initial cookie's domain was set the way it was.