# How to extend member session time in PHP

Tags: php, session

When I login to the site. The session closes after about a minute. I checked the php.ini file and there is no problem.

**php.ini**

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 99999999
session.save_path = "/tmp"
```

This is the code in **index.php**

```
<? ob_start(); include 'functions.php'; if(isset($_GET['sess_id']) && $_GET['sess_id']!= "") { session_id($_GET['sess_id']); }
```

This is also **function.php**

```
ob_start();
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.'.str_replace('www.','',$_SERVER['HTTPS_HOST']));
session_name('ses_name');
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
ini_set("display_errors",0);
```

Where do I have to fix this? What should I check?

Comment: You are setting the lifetime to zero `session_set_cookie_params(0,...`

Comment: You should not touch any of these settings anyways. It'll fallback to php.ini, as it should.

Comment: @bub Where should this code be inserted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://de.php.net/session_set_cookie_params and try to set the first parameter to a higher value like 24 hours `session_set_cookie_params(24*60*60, ...)`

Comment: Another hint: You should always use session_regenerate_id(); after session_start(). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965067/when-and-why-i-should-use-session-regenerate-id

Comment: I'm setting to session_set_cookie_params and it look working nice. Thank you.