# What is the difference between session_create_id and session_regenerate_id()?

Tags: php, session

Doc says

`session_create_id()` is used to create new session id for the current session.
`session_regenerate_id()` Update the current session id with a newly generated one.

Is there any difference between these two functions ?

Comment: you can already read it.. `create` and `update`, but accurately `session_regenerate_id()` will replace the current session id with a new one, and keep the current session information.

Comment: "new id" for current session & update with "new id" does it look same ?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965067/when-and-why-i-should-use-session-regenerate-id

Comment: figured out that by default session_regenerate_id() = session_id ( session_create_id() ) right ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a difference, `session_create_id()` will create a new sessionId discarding the current `$_SESSION` information, where as `session_regenerate_id()` doesn't destroys them, instead it just updates the sessionId

Referred from : http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-create-id.php & http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php

Answer (score 1):

[session_create_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-create-id.php)

> Create new session id

[session_regenerate_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php)

> Update the current session id with a newly generated one

**Usage example from the manual:**

```
$old_sessionid = session_id();

// Set destroyed timestamp
$_SESSION['destroyed'] = time(); // Since PHP 7.0.0 and up, session_regenerate_id() saves old session data

// Simply calling session_regenerate_id() may result in lost session, etc.
// See next example.
session_regenerate_id();

// New session does not need destroyed timestamp
unset($_SESSION['destroyed']);

$new_sessionid = session_id();

echo "Old Session: $old_sessionid<br />";
echo "New Session: $new_sessionid<br />";

print_r($_SESSION);
```

Which leads us to the following question - why and when you should use it, there's a detailed answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965067/when-and-why-i-should-use-session-regenerate-id).