# What is the difference between session_id(), session_create_id() and session_regenerate_id() in php?

Tags: php, php-7, php-7.1, php-7.2

What is the difference between
**session_id()**, **session_create_id()** and **session_regenerate_id()** in php ?

I am already on php.net but there is a un-explained and broad definition of these 3 functions which cannot be understand well.

There are also 50% similar questions asked on stack overflow but no answer is accepted.

Can anyone tell in simple words?

Comment: Quicklinks for future access: [session_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php)  -  [session_create_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-create-id.php)  -  [session_regenerate_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php).

Comment: *"but there is a simple and broad definition of these 3 functions which cannot be understand well."* - It's not simple then. Seeing the edit, this comment as per the original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47487292/1

Comment: I am already on php.net. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: I have edit my question. Please read again thank you

Comment: Open and study the comment left by @FirstOne

Comment: @RamsésFernández Instead of posting it as a comment, you can flag the question as a possible duplicate. A quick "FYI" ;-) if the community agrees, it could be closed for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between session\_create\_id and session\_regenerate\_id()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46947421/what-is-the-difference-between-session-create-id-and-session-regenerate-id)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Done thanks you :)

Comment: Now I'm confused why the accepted answer is more detailed than the manual. (Btw, dupe-voting is for consolidation; instead of smearing answer thins across dozens of similar questions.)

Comment: Difference between **session_id()** and **session_create_id()** ???

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**session_id():**

> Get and/or set the current session id

**session_regenerate_id():**

> Update the current session id with a newly generated one

**session_create_id():**

> Create new session id

Here is a link to the [PHP sessions doc](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) and [PHP docs](http://php.net/docs.php)

Comment: One thing is not clear if **session_id()** sets the session id then why **session_create_id()** ? Both set session id ? Or may be any difference between them ?

Comment: accept this answer? no please don't. Check the various duplicates in the comment section

Comment: @Akintunde- The link you shared has no accepted answer. Who is sure that the answer on the link page is correct, ha?

Comment: this answer has been downvoted twice. Is accepting a downvoted low-rated answer the best idea?

Comment: One thing is not clear if session_id() sets the session id then why session_create_id() ? Both set session id ? Or may be any difference between them ?

Comment: Dear Fred One thing is not clear if **session_id()** sets the session id then why using **session_create_id()** ? Both sets the session id ? Or may be any difference between them ?