# Session gets erased or deleted when calling session_regenerate_id()

Tags: php, apache, session, cookies, session-cookies

Here is a simple page I have:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['test'])) {
    $_SESSION['test'] = time();
} else {
    session_regenerate_id(true);
}

print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

So it checks if session exists. If it does not exist, then it will set a value. In this example, it is `time()` so we can see if it has changed or not.

If the session is set, we call `session_regenerate_id(true)` but. It should keep showing the same `time()` since we have already set it in the first place, but it keeps showing different times on each refresh. I've tried removing the "true" in the regenerate function but it still does not work.

Anyone can help?

Comment: @RaymondNijland but the session info should still transfer over to the new session, right?

Comment: it should but also read what the PHP devs warn about `session_regenerate_id()` usage on unstabile internet connections..  Example #2  code is better then using `session_regenerate_id()` keep it mind it is more or less pseudo code.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I've tried it on multiple internet networks already. It works for my other site but not on this new one

Comment: *"It works for my other site but not on this new one "* different PHP versions?  Also try [session_write_close()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)

Comment: @RaymondNijland Both are PHP 7.2. I tried `session_write_close();` and it did not work

Comment: @RaymondNijland In this answer it states that the session data should not be destroyed https://stackoverflow.com/a/46947572/4357238

Comment: *"In this answer it states that the session data should not be destroyed "* i said it should right?   Annyhow  let PHP run in debugging mode -> `ini_set('display_errors,' 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`   if this does not show annything.. I don't know why this random feature is happening on one server with the same PHP version.. As It does not have PHP version depening code unless the session configuration is different offcource.

Comment: @RaymondNijland No errors at all