# PHP session variables not carrying over to my admin page once I redirect from login to admin page

Tags: php, session

I have a Login Page; if username and password match with database will redirect to admin; but on admin page Iam not getting session variables.
first my login page:

```
<?php
session_start(); //Start the session
session_regenerate_id(true); 
//print_r($_SESSION);
use Ct\Ct\Data\Data;
extract($_POST);
$eventlists = Data::getpassword();
foreach ($eventlists as $eventlist) {
    $get_list_username = $eventlist->user_name;
    $get_list_password = $eventlist->user_pass;
}
//echo $get_list_username.'outside'; 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $your_name = $_POST['username'];
    $your_password = $_POST['password'];
    $_SESSION['usr'] = $your_name;
    $_SESSION['pwd'] = $your_password;
    //echo $_SESSION['username'];
    if($_SESSION['usr'] == $get_list_username && $_SESSION['pwd'] == $get_list_password) {
        print('<script>window.location.href="https://ct.org/admin-gunpage-update/"</script>');                  
    }
    else {
       echo '<center><b style="color:red;position: relative;left: -27%;">Invalide username or password, please check again!   </b></center>';             
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Login Gun Page Update</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="login" id="login" method="POST" action="">
    <label class="log_in"> LOGIN </label>
    <p><label for="username" class="username">Username: </label><input type="text" size="100" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="UserName"/></p>
    <p><label for="password" class="password">Password: </label><input type="password" size="40" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password"/></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Submit"/> <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" class="reset" value="reset"/></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

then admin page:

```
<?php
session_start(); //Start the session
print_r($_SESSION);
if(!isset($_SESSION['usr']))      // if there is no valid session
{
    print('<script>window.location.href="https://ct.org/login-gun-page-updates/"</script>');
    //echo 'NOT working !!';
}
echo $_SESSION['usr'];
use Ct\Ct\Data\Data;
extract($_POST);
if(isset($save))
{
    Data::getupdate($ticketsavailable);     
    print('<script>window.location.href="https://ct.org/gun-drawing/"</script>');
}
$ticketleft = "";
$ticketleft = Data::getticketsavailable();
//print_r($ticketleft);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>update page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <label class="update_heading"> UPDATE  TICKETS </label> <a href='https://ct.org/logout-gunpage-update-form/' class="logout_link" > Logout</a><br>
    <label for="update" class="update"> Update Number: </label><input type="textbox" id="ticketsavailable" name="ticketsavailable" value="<?php echo $ticketleft[0]->ticket_available; ?>"/><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a Login Page; if username and password match with database will redirect to admin; but on admin page I am not getting session variables.
I did `print_r($_SESSION);` it shows empty on admin page. And I have started session on both page please help!!
please help I am not having time!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When and why I should use session\_regenerate\_id()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965067/when-and-why-i-should-use-session-regenerate-id)

Comment: If i remove session_regenerate_id(); still it does not work!!! please help

Comment: I don't know where to start debugging this mess; first of all, you're setting `$_SESSION['usr']` to the form's user even if the login data doesn't match. And you're redirecting using echoed JS instead of `header("Location: ...");` - And why are you overwriting `$get_list_username` multiple times in your loop? And why do you have `extract($_POST)` but then don't use any of the generated variables?

Comment: redirecting using echoed JS instead of header("Location: ..."); because this header is working fine on Local server but on LIVE its not working...

Comment: and where Am I overwriting $get_list_username multiple times , this $get_list_username contains username value from my database i just compared it with my session value

Comment: In the foreach loop at the top.

Comment: In the foreach loop through this  $eventlist variable i get value from column ->user_name; and store it in $get_list_username and the compare with session ;

Comment: Exactly. That is where you are overwriting `$get_list_username` multiple times. I don't know what exactly `Data::getpassword()` is returning, but if it's an array, you're setting the two variables to what the last element stores. But this is unrelated to your session issue. However if you can't even get `header("Location: ...");` to work, you have bigger problems.

Comment: public function getpassword()
    {
     global $wpdb;
        
  $eventslist = $wpdb->get_results("select user_name,user_pass FROM login_admin where id = 1"); 
  
  return $eventslist;
    }

Comment: Put it in the question. Don't put code in comments.

Comment: for now my problem is iam not getting session variables on admin page.

Comment: Try this: https://pastebin.com/gu2mHtiC

Comment: It is working on LOCAL but iam afraid to update it on LIVE...

Comment: Its not working on LIVE array is still empty on admin page and it does not open admin again it redirects back to login page again and again!

Comment: In that case you need to start looking for the error somewhere else. Check in the browser's network tab which cookies are sent. Use another browser entirely. Clear all cookies. Etc.

Comment: Its showing no cookies send on admin page when i checked in network tab

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion is
first you login then store username with some user access key in session ex.`($_SESSION['username']=$username);` and store user access in another session variable `($_SESSION['useraccess']="admin");` after login successfully, use this session for other webpage

Comment: The issue is the entire `$_SESSION` getting lost between pages, I don't see how this answer solves that problem.